# Can't boot into Ubuntu after succesful installation alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, acer

I'm having trouble booting my Ubuntu installation. I have tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to be working...

I have an Acer TravelMate X349 with a 256GB SSD and pre-installed Windows 10. I want to have both OS on the SSD and be able to select from them in the boot menu.

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370) guide to create partitions alongside Windows 10 and install Ubuntu. It worked fine and the installation is complete.
After restarting and going into the boot menu (F12) I can't find the Ubuntu installation. I set the boot priority for Windows on the lowest number in the BIOS boot menu. Everything is set to UEFI (Boot mode and Ubuntu USB installer).

I read somewhere that I have to set the Ubuntu bootloader (GBR i think?) as the primary loader. How do I do this?

My partitions look like this:

- [Before the Ubuntu installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIMpc.png)
- [After the installation and booting from the USB-Stick again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aft9F.png)

I use /dev/sda as the "Device for boot loader installation"
[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25835078/) is my Boot Info. *No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda* doesn't sound right...

Other things I tried are:

- Different USB Stick
- Ubuntu 17.10
- Ubuntu 16.04.3
- Different USB Tools (Yumi, putty, etzy)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

Follow [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/#Acer-Rechner) guide to configure your EFI. Here is a quick translation:

- Get in BIOS (UEFI) setup
- Set a "Set Supervisor Password:"
- set "Boot Mode:" to [UEFI]
- set "Secure Boot" to [Enabled]

After the istalation of Ubuntu via USB Stick you need to configure your UEFI to show the grub boot loader:

- Open the BIOS with F2
- *Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing*
- navigate to *HDD0 -> EFI -> ubuntu -> shimx64.efi*
- Enter a recognizable name for you

After that, all should run smoothly.
Note: Only Ubuntu 17.10 and higher supports all the driver you need. 16.04 was quite troublesome...